# Java SaxParser gets null value, tag not found

Tags: java, saxparser

To start learning to use the Saxparser I have a very small XML file I want to parse.
my XML file:

edit: (note: each entry will have an id for identification. my goal at the end wil be to be able to parse a more complex xml file with each having an id)

```
<entry id="2000" >
  <word>"hello"</word>
</entry>
```

Now I create an entry class:

```
public class Entry {
private int id;
private String word;

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entry:: ID="+this.id+" word=" + this.word;
}
}
```

my extended Default handler:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<Entry> wordList = null;
private Entry word = null;

public List<Entry> getwordList() {
    return wordList;
}

boolean bword = false;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
        String id = attributes.getValue("id");
        word = new Entry();
        word.setID(Integer.parseInt(id));
        if (wordList == null) {
            wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("word")) {
            bword = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
        wordList.add(word);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (bword) {
        word.setWord(new String(ch, start, length));
        bword = false;
    }
}

}
```

and finally I run it here:

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        saxParser.parse(new File("/home/user/Desktop/test.xml"), handler);
        //get verb liste
        List<Entry> wordList = handler.getwordList();
        //print verb
        for (Entry word : wordList)
            System.out.print(word);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the result is as follows:

```
   Entry:: ID=2000 word=null
```

I know the problem is somewhere in startElement because it set my bword as false or it doesnt recognize the the tag. because if I set the characters method as true for if (bword) { etc. it gives me

```
  Entry:: ID=2000 word=
```

instead of

```
 Entry:: ID=2000 word=null
```

Comment: This code would not work at all. Not all elements in your file have attribute "id" hence `word.setID(Integer.parseInt(id));` should throw NPE.

Comment: thank ou for your replay @fukanchik. my elements would all have Ids for identification. for now I only have one element to start testing. But in the end it will be a more complex xml file to parse with each element having an id.

Comment: `qName.equalsIgnoreCase("eintrag")` adds new word to the list. Since there are no `eintrag`s in the xml no word is added. You should not see any entries printed at all

Comment: @fukanchik I'm sorry that was my mistake. I corrected the code. the naming of my elements were in german at first but I changed them all to englisch with missing that one. it should be entry instead.

Comment: there is error in your updated logic: `if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {` wraps around `if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("word"))`. this makes the condition look like: `if qName=entry AND qName=word then bword = true` which would never work of course. You need to correct curly braces to make it work.

Comment: @fukanchik that was the problem! thank you very much. I was looking at all the wrong places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fukanchic who explained and pointed out the error: the curly braces were set wrong

here the corrected MyHandler part.

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<Entry> wordList = null;
private Entry word = null;

public List<Entry> getwordList() {
return wordList;
}

boolean bword = false;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
    String id = attributes.getValue("id");
    word = new Entry();
    word.setID(Integer.parseInt(id));
    if (wordList == null) 
        wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("word")) {
        bword = true;
    }
}


@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("entry")) {
    wordList.add(word);
}
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
if (bword) {
    word.setWord(new String(ch, start, length));
    bword = false;
    }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the class MyHandler you have a "German"? word...

```
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("eintrag")) {
```

it must be entry I guess

and the exception is because

you are not checking that not all child elements has no attribute id... like the Word element...

so here:

```
String id = attributes.getValue("id");
    word = new Entry();

        word.setID(Integer.parseInt(id));
```

id is null and then you will try to parse to int a null that is exploding the code...

Comment: I'm sorry that was my mistake. it shoudl be entry and not eintrag. with entry instead of eintrag it will give me the result mentioned above with word=null